# Analog clock using braille UTF8 characters

Tags: code-golf, clock

Inspired by [Braille graphics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/140624/9424) and [Build an analog clock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10759/9424).

- The goal there is to create a tool that use terminal console to draw and animate a clock by using UTF-8 fonts `\U2800`: `⠀` to `\U28FF`: `⣿`.

  ```
  00:[⠀] 01:[⠁] 02:[⠂] 03:[⠃] 04:[⠄] 05:[⠅] 06:[⠆] 07:[⠇] 08:[⠈] 09:[⠉] 0A:[⠊]
  0B:[⠋] 0C:[⠌] 0D:[⠍] 0E:[⠎] 0F:[⠏] 10:[⠐] 11:[⠑] 12:[⠒] 13:[⠓] 14:[⠔] 15:[⠕] 
  ...
  EA:[⣪] EB:[⣫] EC:[⣬] ED:[⣭] EE:[⣮] EF:[⣯] F0:[⣰] F1:[⣱] F2:[⣲] F3:[⣳] F4:[⣴]
  F5:[⣵] F6:[⣶] F7:[⣷] F8:[⣸] F9:[⣹] FA:[⣺] FB:[⣻] FC:[⣼] FD:[⣽] FE:[⣾] FF:[⣿]
  ```
- The program takes `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` -- the height and width of the displayed clock in terminal characters -- as input.
- From `pixelWidth = WIDTH x 2` and `pixelHeight = HEIGHT x 4` you have to build something like a map, drawn your clock as described then extract 2 pixel width and 4 pixel height characters to choose one of 256 character in `\U2800` to `\U28FF`.
- They must be upgraded every second!! Care of code efficiency! (not 1 second delay plus drawing time) **+25 byte penalty if your clock drop any second!**
- The full circle of the clock is 1 point width, at 100% of ray, meaning ray could vary between horizontal (`ray=pixelWidth/2`) and vertical (`ray=pixelHeight/2`)!
- 12 hour ticks from 90% to 100% of ray.
- 60 minute ticks as single dot located at 90%, but displayed only if `width > 20` (terminal width greather than 20 characters).
- Hours arm length is 45% of ray.
- Minutes arm length is 77% of ray.
- Seconds arm is 88% or ray.
- Seconds arm is 1 point width.
- Hours and minutes arms have to be larger, for this, you will draw each of them 3 time: 1x centered, 1x shifted left by 1 dot and 1x shifted up by 1 dot.
- Hours, minutes and seconds arms have to progress each second like a regular analog clock.
- Of course, there could be some *variants*, mostly depending on how you drawn the circle. But as other graphic parts are lines, except some rare rounding bug, with a give size, at some precise time, all clock program could show same design... with some `1px` difference somewhere... Some sample you could copy-paste:

  A `18x8` clock at `10h10'42"` like (without minutes ticks):

  ```
  ⠀⠀⠀⢀⣤⠒⠊⠉⠉⠋⠉⠑⠒⣤⡀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⢠⠊⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠑⡄⠀
  ⢸⠓⠀⠀⠀⣀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣠⣤⠀⠚⡇
  ⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠛⢷⣦⣤⡶⠟⠛⠉⠀⠀⠀⢸
  ⡏⠀⣀⡠⠔⠒⠊⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢹
  ⢸⡤⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢤⡇
  ⠀⠘⢄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡠⠃⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠈⠛⠤⢄⣀⣀⣄⣀⡠⠤⠛⠁⠀⠀⠀
  ```

  A '39x15`@`3h42'02"`:

  ```
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⡠⠤⠒⠒⠊⠉⡉⠉⢹⠉⢉⠉⠑⠒⠒⠤⢄⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡠⠒⠙⡆⠀⠂⠈⠀⠈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡸⠁⠀⠁⠐⠀⢰⠋⠒⢄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠒⠁⠠⠈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠁⠄⠈⠒⢄⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⣠⠊⠀⠄⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡜⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠠⠀⠑⣄⠀⠀
  ⠀⡰⠉⡉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠃⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠐⢉⠉⢆⠀
  ⢰⠁⠠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠄⠈⡆
  ⡎⢀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⡀⢱
  ⡧⠤⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣀⣤⣤⡶⠶⠶⠾⠶⢶⣤⣄⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠤⢼
  ⢇⠈⡀⠀⢀⣀⣤⣤⡶⠶⠟⠛⠛⠉⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠙⠛⠻⠆⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠁⡸
  ⠸⡀⠐⠀⠈⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠂⢀⠇
  ⠀⠱⣀⣁⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣈⣀⠎⠀
  ⠀⠀⠙⢄⠀⠂⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠐⠀⡠⠋⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠑⠤⡀⠐⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠂⢀⠤⠊⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠑⠤⣠⠇⠀⠄⢀⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⡀⠠⠀⠸⣄⠤⠊⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠑⠒⠤⠤⢄⣀⣁⣀⣸⣀⣈⣀⡠⠤⠤⠒⠊⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ```

  Or a `48x24` @ `9h16'23"`:

  ```
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⠤⠤⠒⠒⠊⠉⠉⠉⡏⠉⠉⠑⠒⠒⠤⠤⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⡔⠊⠉⠀⠀⡀⠀⠄⠀⠂⠀⠀⠃⠀⠐⠀⠠⠀⢀⠀⠀⠉⠑⢢⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠔⠊⠀⢳⠀⠐⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠂⠀⡞⠀⠑⠢⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠔⠁⠀⠀⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠐⠀⠀⠈⠢⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠔⠁⢀⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⡀⠈⠢⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⢠⠊⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⠑⡄⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⡰⠓⠦⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠠⠴⠚⢆⠀⠀
  ⠀⢠⠃⠀⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠠⠀⠘⡄⠀
  ⠀⡇⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⢸⠀
  ⢸⠀⢀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⡇
  ⡎⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠀⢱
  ⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠛⠛⠻⠶⠶⠶⣦⣤⣤⣄⣀⣀⣀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸
  ⡏⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠙⣍⠙⠛⠻⠶⢶⣤⣄⣀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠉⢹
  ⢇⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠣⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠉⠛⠛⠷⠶⣦⣤⣄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⡸
  ⢸⠀⠈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠢⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠁⠀⡇
  ⠀⡇⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⢆⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⢸⠀
  ⠀⠘⡄⠀⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠑⢄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠐⠀⢠⠃⠀
  ⠀⠀⠱⡤⠖⠂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠓⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠐⠲⢤⠎⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠘⢄⠀⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠣⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠀⡠⠃⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠢⡀⠈⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠢⢀⠀⠁⢀⠔⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠢⡀⠀⠀⠄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠠⠀⠀⢀⠔⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠢⢄⠀⡼⠀⠠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠄⠀⢧⠀⡠⠔⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠣⢄⣀⠀⠀⠁⠀⠂⠀⠄⠀⠀⡄⠀⠠⠀⠐⠀⠈⠀⠀⣀⡠⠜⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠒⠒⠤⠤⢄⣀⣀⣀⣇⣀⣀⡠⠤⠤⠒⠒⠉⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
  ```

There is an accelerated sample of what they could look like, in a `80x24` terminal window, shot between `09h17'00"` and `09h18'00"`

[image: braille-clock-09h17-09h18.gif]

Another sample in a small `20x10` window shot between `09h59` and `10h00`:

[image: braille-clock-tiny-09h59-10h00]

This is code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what is required for this to challenge to work as code golf. Remember that the goal for solvers is to save as many bytes as possible while meeting the specification however minimally or literally, with no value on how nice the output is, so solvers need to know just how much or little is required in their ASCII art output.

Comment: @xnor I don't understand your comment... Clock must be drawable at any width and height, I think I did not miss something in requirement, Size of draw could be submited as argument, like: `drawBrailleClock $COLUMNS $LINES`. From there ray may vary between horizontal and vertical. size of path, tick and border is explained...

Comment: For instance, what characters should the outer circle be made of? What  does something like "minute path are 2 point width" mean when it's tilted? For the challenge to be fully specified, one needs to be able to derive exactly what symbol is to displayed at each coordinate for any size.

Comment: Ok, So in a 45° angle, *2 to 3 point witdh* could use upto 4 points horizontaly and verticaly `⠻⣷⣄`.... answer edited

Comment: I would recommend posting future challenges in our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first. This seems like a neat idea, but there are some things that need to be clarified. In order to make this challenge well-specified enough for us to golf, it would be useful if you provided an ungolfed example program, or some pseudocode to show us how you want the results formatted. It may seem perfectly clear to you as the author, but we can't be entirely sure of what to output without more specification.

Comment: @xnor Question edited: I hope this could be reopened!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms This question was edited. I think there is everything specified! If not, please tell me what's unclear...

Comment: @F.Hauri I think it's good now. You might want to specify exactly how the braille symbols should be chosen (or provide an example program), but for now I'll VTR since it's close enough in my opinion.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I've added a 3rd paragraph, trying to answer your comment. Is this readable?

Comment: @F.Hauri Yep, looks good!

Comment: how much graphical difference is allowed from the clock shown in your question? Do you have a reference implementation?

Comment: We have a list of [default input formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), requiring specific input formats is unnecessary and could be problematic -- although you can roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Razetime that's definitely hard to answer... but I assume that you can allow anything that "looks correct, with the correct components"

Comment: @xnor I see that the line drawing algorithms are not very well-specified, but so is every [tag:graphical-output] challenges. (for example  https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211460/plot-a-centered-circle ) Why is this one different?

Comment: @xnor Added a paragraph with  tolerance. and some sample could be copied as UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I've added some penalty, This is ok while no answer already exist and question still closed!?

Comment: Let's wait for xnor on that part. I think it's okay to not specify the line drawing algorithm. // Currently there are 3 reopen votes, and I didn't vote to reopen.

Comment: @xnor? // Aw, the reopen votes aged away.